# Excel function to match rows and move cells?

Tags: excel

Excel sheet:
Row A - 2000 product codes
Row B - prices

Row C - 2400 product codes
Row D - product descriptions

Codes on row A and C match about 95%. I need to make just one list with: code, description, price. But manually filter out the product codes that dont have to price and cant be used, is very time consuming. So I need a function that basically compares rows A and C and moves the price to match the correct code and description.

Hopefully that was clear enough :)

Comment: Please clarify if you want to say as columns instead of rows? Also, give an example to explain in a better way.

Answer (score 1):

Try using vlookup, here's an example where I inserted a new col. B (new desc) with the product code descriptions

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Take columns `C` and `D` and move them to another sheet since they lack a good relationship with Columns `A` and `D`, for starters.

If the original sheet is `Sheet1` and the new sheet is `Sheet2` then in `Sheet2!C`1 (the first blank column in `Sheet2`) use a `Vlookup` formula to grab the prices from `sheet1` for each Product code:

```
=vlookup(Sheet2!A1, Sheet1!A:B, 2, false)
```

This will return prices from the second column of Range `Sheet1!A:B` where the first column `Sheet1!A` contains the same product code as in `Sheet2!A1`. Copy this formula down and you will pick up prices for every row in Sheet2!